# Javascript | remove unwanted data from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I just want first year and last year element from Array Object

example this is the data ( it is sorted so I just don't wanna messed that up) :

```
[
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2015' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2020' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2033' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2010' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2020' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2030' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2040' }
]
```

and I want it like this all the middle years removed :

```
[
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2020' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2033' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2010' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2040' }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not sort it by the years first, then by make? You could then just separate the array by make, and then grab the first and last values.

Comment: why only one object for `'rs5'`?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm assuming they're getting the latest and oldest by make, not model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just separate the array by make, and then grab the first and last values of each make:

```js
const arr = [
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2015' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2020' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2033' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2010' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2020' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2030' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2040' }
]

const grouped = arr.reduce((a, el) => (a[el.make] ? a[el.make].push(el) : a[el.make] = [el], a), {})
const out = Object.values(grouped).reduce((a, group) => (a.push(group[0], group[group.length - 1]), a), [])

console.log(out)
```

Comment: OP hasn't specified how to handle that case, I'm not sure which one they would want to pick. Unless I've missed something...

Comment: Thanks Kobe it really helped me a lot.

Comment: @SRTechConnect No problem, if you need more help, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array by looking for the next to last item and if it has the same `make` as the actual object, then update the last index.

Otherwise push the object to the result set.

This approach uses the sorted array by `make` and `year`.

```js
var data = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2015' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2020' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2033' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2010' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2020' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2030' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2040' }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if ((r[r.length - 2] || {}).make === o.make) r[r.length - 1] = o; 
        else r.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is sorted then try this

```
var newcar = [];
var myvar = [];
for (var i=0; i<(car.length)-1; i++) {
    if(car[i].make == car[i+1].make) 
    {
        myvar.push(car[i]);
        if(i+1 == car.length-1)
        {
            myvar.push(car[i+1]);
            newcar.push(myvar[0]);
            var lastitem = myvar.pop();
            newcar.push(lastitem);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        myvar.push(car[i]);
        newcar.push(myvar[0]);
        var lastitem = myvar.pop();
        newcar.push(lastitem);
        myvar = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use filter method on the array, you can find docs in the following https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/es6-array-filter-method/
and

example:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr.filter((i) => {
// A Condition, if true it's displayed if not it's discarded
return i > 2;
}));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can loop through the array and save the ones with the maximum and minimum year like this:

```js
let data = [
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2015' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2020' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2033' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2010' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2020' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2030' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2040' }
];

let a = {};

for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
  if( !a[data[i].make] ) {
    a[data[i].make] = {};
  }
  if( !a[data[i].make].max || a[data[i].make].max.year < data[i].year ) {
    a[data[i].make].max = data[i];
  }
  if( !a[data[i].make].min || a[data[i].make].min.year > data[i].year ) {
    a[data[i].make].min = data[i];
  }
}

let output = [];

Object.keys(a).forEach(make => {
  output.push( a[make].min );
  output.push( a[make].max );
});

console.dir( output );
```